# How can I solve this PDE: $u_{tt}(\mathbf{x},t)+ku_t(\mathbf{x},t)-c^2 \Delta u(\mathbf{x},t)=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Consider the wave equation:

$$u_{tt}(\mathbf{x},t)+ku_t(\mathbf{x},t)-c^2 \Delta u(\mathbf{x},t)=0$$

$\mathbf{x}\in\Bbb R^2, t>0 \\ \space \\ u(\mathbf{x},0)=0 \\ u_t(\mathbf{x},0)=\psi(\mathbf{x})$

a) Determine $\alpha \in \Bbb R$ such that $v(\mathbf{x},t):=e^{\alpha t}u(\mathbf{x},t)$ satisfies a first order PDE without first order derivatives on $\Bbb R^2$

b) Determine a $\beta \in \Bbb R$ such that $w(x_1,x_2,x_3,t)=w(\mathbf{x},x_3,t):=e^{\beta x_3}v(\mathbf{x},t)$ satisfies a PDE on $\Bbb R^2$ with second order derivatives only

c) Show that the solution of the PDE is: $$u(\mathbf{x},t)=\frac{e^{-kt/2}}{2 \pi c} \int_{\lvert y \rvert >ct}d^2y \frac{\cosh(\frac{k}{2c}\sqrt{c^2t^2-\lvert y \rvert^2})}{\sqrt{c^2t^2-\lvert y \rvert^2}}\psi(x+y)$$

---

I don't even know how to start solving this problem. a) and b) doesn't make any sense to me. Can anyone explain why I am trying to find $\alpha$ and $\beta$ and what these constants mean?

c) Looks a bit like the 2-D Poisson-Formula but as far as I understand the Poisson-Formula only applies to PDE's without a dissipation term.

I also don't understand how a) and b) will lead me to figuring out c). Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Where did this question come from? Setting $\alpha$ and $\beta = 0$ satisfies your original PDE and hence the conditions required in each part, though I doubt that is what you are after. For part $c)$, you're probably best off using the Fourier transform. The PDE is called the Telegraph equation.

Comment: It's from a practice exam from my university. I guess $\alpha=\beta=0$ is a trivial solution and I am not sure if that is what the questioner had in mind. Could you elaborate c)? Knowing the name of the PDE already helps a lot. Thanks!

Comment: Could you post a link to the exam? Also, I'm being technical, but I wouldn't call $\alpha = \beta = 0$ a _trivial solution_; $u = 0$ is the trivial solution . And for $c)$, just apply the [Fourier transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform).

Comment: I am afraid I can't. You have to have access to the course website in order to look at it. I took a screenshot and attached it to my question. I also found a somewhat similar problem here: http://www.math.umbc.edu/~jbell/pde_notes/07_Telegrapher%20Equation.pdf but I can't really make sense of the substitution. Maybe you can.

Comment: Sure, I'll look at it now. For part $c)$, just differentiate the solution given and show it satisfies the PDE given if you haven't learnt how to Fourier transform.

Comment: @Mattos Thanks! I should have thought of that myself. Also, thanks for taking a look at the link.

Comment: Ok, I got it. I just read the question incorrectly to begin with because I'm tired. I'll make a post now for part $a)$ if you would like.

Comment: Great! That would be awesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For part $a)$, defining $v := e^{\alpha t} u \implies u = e^{- \alpha t} v$ and hence

\begin{align}
u_{t} &= e^{- \alpha t} (v_{t} - \alpha v) \\
u_{tt} &= e^{- \alpha t} (v_{tt} - 2 \alpha v_{t} + \alpha^{2} v) \\
\Delta u &= e^{- \alpha t} \Delta v
\end{align}

Hence (check this yourself)

\begin{align}
u_{tt} + k u_{t} - c^{2} \Delta u &= v_{tt} + (k - 2 \alpha) v_{t} + (\alpha^{2} - c^{2} \Delta) v \quad (1) \\
&= 0
\end{align}

In order for no first order partial derivatives to exist, we need to eliminate the $v_{t}$ term by setting the coefficient to $0$. So we require

$$k - 2 \alpha = 0 \implies \alpha = \frac{k}{2}$$

and hence

$$u(\mathbf{x}, t) = \exp \bigg( {- \frac{kt}{2}} \bigg) v(\mathbf{x}, t)$$

A similar approach is required for part $b)$ in order to remove the $\alpha^{2} v$ term from $(1)$, which I'll leave to you. As stated above, for part $c)$ just take the derivatives of the integral solution and show it satisfies the PDE.

Comment: Thank you so much! This helped me a lot.